# Accidentally overwrote boot sector of encrypted drive: any way to recover data?

Tags: encryption, data-recovery

I had one external drive on which I was storing a large quantity of data; the drive is/was encrypted using gnome disk utility.  I got a second drive for redundancy and I was preparing to encrypt it.  Unfortunately, I overwrote the device book partition for the original external drive:

```
~$ sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb1
15585+0 records in
15584+0 records out
7979008 bytes (8.0 MB) copied, 1.30506 s, 6.1 MB/s
```

So that is a disaster.  Curse my fat fingers.  Is there anything I can do to restore access to the drive?

Some output from fdisk below.  Device mounted as `sdb` was the original drive, the device at sdc the new drive.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398839808 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30400 cylinders, total 488378623 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1   488378622  1953514488   ee  GPT

...

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204138496 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953523708 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x7e3058f0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  1953519615   976758784    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```